# How do I disable or hide the big picture mode option on steam?

Tags: steam

The steam big picture mode is really annoying on my desktop.  Because of its location (right below the useful min/max/close buttons), and right above the "Friends" item in the right click menu, sometimes I accidentally enable it.

The problem is, every time I exit big picture mode it causes my steam to crash and I have to relaunch the application.

Since I will never use it on my desktop, is there a way I can disable the option completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It [doesn't look like it](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/846938351007807643/?l=french) - although quite a few people are asking for it. If you use the default skin for Steam, you can download [this tweaked clone](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3023158) of that skin which moves the button away from the minimise/maximise buttons, and makes it smaller. For the time being though, Valve haven't given us the option to get rid of this new feature.

Comment: PS: I wish I hadn't just updated Steam to check for methods of getting rid of it. :(

Comment: that stinks :(  I'm hoping they push out a way to get rid of it soon

Comment: I imagine if it turns out to be *that* unpopular, then an option will appear on the 'interface' tab in steam settings soonish

Answer (score 3):

Go to the top of Steam and click View>Small Mode

Not the most aesthetically pleasing view in my opinion, but it will solve your problem of accidentally clicking the Big Picture Mode button.

Comment: I changed to small mode back when they updated Steam to be the Web 2.0 style thing it is now. It took a while to get used to, but it is so much nicer to use now. It's a shame you can't access Tools through it though.

Answer (score -1):

In the taskbar menu go to 
settings>interface>set taskbar preferences
uncheck "Big Picture"

[image]

Comment: This will not remove the Big Picture button from the library windows as asked by the OP.